# php's file_get_contents provokes crash

Tags: php, apache2

I am having some trouble with PHP's file_get_contents function.

My setup is basically as follows:
-> From a php page (let's call it a.php), a POST request is sent to another php page (b.php) through file_get_contents.

-> b.php does some stuff with the POST input and then sends another POST request through file_get_contents to itself (b.php)

->This is repeated a couple of times (for example 4 times), so basically it looks like this:

a.php -> POST request through file_get_contents -> b.php -> POST request through file_get_contents -> b.php -> POST request through file_get_contents -> b.php -> POST request through file_get_contents -> b.php

At the last post request to b.php, the script echoes something to the "poster", he adds something to it etc. etc. all the way back to a.php.

For clarity's sake: in production all those php files will be on different servers, and each server has an added value in the process.

For testing however, all pages are on the same server (and I add "?server=x" to the URL so that the same file uses a different database at every "call").

This works like a charm :) ... Unless there are more than 5 file_get_contents are "active" simultaneously ... 
This works fine:
a.php->b.php->b.php->b.php->b.php
This doesn't:
a.php->b.php->b.php->b.php->b.php->b.php
As a matter of fact it crashes my server (not responding to ANY http requests anymore), and only restarting Apache "deblocks" it.
The same happens when I load the working "circuit" a.php->b.php->b.php->b.php->b.php different times from the browser.

Error in the Apache error log:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

I thought it might be related to the POST size being too large, but sending a HUGE POST request through the a.php->b.php->b.php->b.php->b.php circuit works just fine ....

So it looks like somehow only 5 simultaneous file_get_contents are allowed ...

Anyone's got some ideas ?

EDIT: As mentioned below, it looks like the real problem is a deadlock, which will not happen in PRD since there will be no "loop" on the same server ... I solved this issue by using CURL instead with a timeout. When a deadlock risks to occur, the curl requests simply time out without freezing the server.
I'm still interested however to get an answer to this question: How can I check/reconfigure the amount of simultaneous requests in Apache2? It's not in the conf file afaik. 
Thanks !!!

Comment: Additional information: I am now trying whether using curl instead of file_get_contents does the job ... However, also if it does, anyone could crash my server by sending > 5 file_get_contents to my server simultaneously, so any solution would be much appreciated !

Comment: If Apache is not configured to handle more than 5 simultaneous requests (which is a possibility on a simple local development server), then what you're describing simply leads to a deadlock.

Comment: @deceze Can you tell me how I can check/reconfigure the amount of simultaneous requests in Apache2? Thx

Comment: Not spontaneously, no. Start by poking around its config file somewhere, perhaps ask a specific question about that here.

Comment: You can edit the question and provide your additional information in the question itself.  That is generally a better way to do it rather than positing a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CURL instead of file_get_contents in this case - although I've never had an issue with this except(!) when using sessions since they lock the process up till the session closes.

Comment: I will, but like I said: Additional information: I am now trying whether using curl instead of file_get_contents does the job ... However, also if it does, anyone could crash my server by sending > 5 file_get_contents to my server simultaneously, so any solution would be much appreciated ! Btw I don't use sessions.